# Stacked Bar Highcharts how to show the values

Tags: highcharts

How to static values in stacked bar chart. Below is the code i am using

```
  $(function () {

                Highcharts.chart('container5', {

                    chart: {
                        type: 'bar'

                    },
                    title: {
                        text: null
                    },
                    xAxis: {
                        categories: [''],
                        lineWidth: 0, // STEP TWO
                        tickWidth: 0, // STEP ONE
                        labels: {
                            enabled: false
                        },


                    },

                    yAxis: {
                        min: 0,
                        title: {
                            text: '  '
                        },
                        labels: {
                            enabled: false,//default is true
                        },
                        gridLineWidth: 0,
                        minorGridLineWidth: 0,


                    },
                    legend: {
                        reversed: true
                    },


                    plotOptions: {
                        series: {
                            stacking: 'normal'
                        },
                        column: { //at the top bar chart values
                            dataLabels: {
                                enabled: true,
                                crop: false,
                                overflow: 'none'
                            }
                        },

                        bar: {
                            dataLabels: {
                                enabled: true,
                                distance: -50,
                                formatter: function () {
                                    var dlabel = this.series.name + '<br/>';
                                    // dlabel += Math.round(this.percentage*100)/100 + ' %';
                                    return dlabel
                                },
                                style: {
                                    color: 'white',
                                },
                            },

                        }

                    },
                    series: [{
                        showInLegend: false,
                        name: '20',
                        data: [20]
                    }, {
                        showInLegend: false,
                        name: '20',
                        data: [20]
                    }, {
                        showInLegend: false,
                        name: '20',
                        data: [20]
                    }, {
                        showInLegend: false,
                        name: '20',
                        data: [20]
                    }, {
                        showInLegend: false,
                        name: '20',
                        data: [20]
                    }]
                });
            });
```

It is the output and refer the attachment.

[image]

In the screenshot marked in red rectangular box, want to show the values. Refer the screenshot attached below

Original Screenshot (sample one)

[image]

Like this screenshot i need to show the values at the top which can be seen at the top.

Comment: Try adding `y: -100` to the `bar.dataLabel` option (before the `formatter`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define multiple data labels and position one of them at the top of the column, for example:

```
series: [{
  ...,
  dataLabels: [{}, {
    format: '20yrs',
    y: -100
  }]
}, ...]
```

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/6m4e8x0y/4909/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.bar.dataLabels

Answer (score 1):

Added,
y: -100 to the bar.dataLabel option (before the formatter) .

Image Output:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mkkCF.png)

At the top of the label some of the name is missing:

**5-9yrs & 15-20yrs ..printing alternatively**

and also inside the stacked bar chart, values "20" not get displayed.